# swift display number of pages a book has

Tags: swift, google-books

So, I am attempting to create a program that uses GoogleBooksClientApi to search for a book that will then display the title of the book, the author's name, the page count and the synopsis. I was able to write the code that pulls the title, name and synopsis because they are of course String variables but I can't for the life of me figure out how to retrieve the page count and my program keeps saying pageCount is an unresolved identifier. Can someone please explain what I need to pull an Int variable?

here is the code I have so far:
    import UIKit
    import GoogleBooksApiClient

```
class FinalDetailViewController: UIViewController {

var data: Volume?


@IBOutlet weak var bookdetails: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var booktitle: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var authorname: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var pages: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let title = data?.volumeInfo.title {
        booktitle.text = title
    }
    if let author = data?.volumeInfo.authors {
        let authors : String = author.reduce("", { $0 == "" ? $1 : $0 + "," + $1 })
       authorname.text = authors
    }

    if let desc = data?.volumeInfo.desc{
        bookdetails.text = desc
    }

    if let page = data?.volumeInfo.pageCount {
        //here is where I don't know what to do

      }
    }
```

If its not obvious by my question, I am new to using Xcode/Swift so please be patient with me and thank you in advance to anyone who is able to help me. I'm assuming its obvious but just in case I'm using Swift 4 and Xcode 9.2.

Comment: According to the documentation, `pageCount` is an integer, so you should be able to set this value to your label like this: ```pages.text = String(page)```

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/reference/volumes), `pageCount` is an integer, so you should be able to set this value to your label like this:

```
if let page = data?.volumeInfo.pageCount {
   pages.text = String(page)
}
```